# Devise: NoMethod Error & user_signed_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I'm trying to use user_signed_in? to add a login area to my rails 3 application using devise 1.1.3 and I get a NoMethodErrorin Rules#index

```
<% if user_signed_in? -%>
<div id="user_login_box" style="float:right">
  <%= current_user.email %> |
  <%= link_to 'My info', edit_user_registration_path %> |
  <%= link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path %>
</div>
<% end -%>
```

I'm not sure what's wrong exactly, but clearly the devise method isn't being used. I'm also fairly (read: really) new to rails and haven't used devise before.

Comment: If, you remove `user_signed_in?` and login, and get to the page displaying your mentioned view, is the `<%= current_user.email %>` displayed or not ?

Comment: It isn't. I get this:
undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<#<Class:0xab9706c>:0xab962d4>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing the call to `devise :database_authenticatable` in your `User` model.

Also, a good way to get started with devise is to look at the **excellent** *RailsCasts by Ryan Bates* :  [Introducing Devise](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise).

Answer (score 5):

What is the name of the model you generated Devise for?

If you called it something else instead of **User**, you might want to check out http://groups.google.com/group/plataformatec-devise/msg/67f1eb5a571b6136

Answer (score 3):

I had the exactly the same issue. 
    `undefined local variable or method 'edit_user_registration_path'`

However, I have `devise :database_authenticatable`, but not `:registerable`.  After I added the `:registerable` everything works!

Answer (score 1):

It also may happen that your trying to call that route from another engine, so in that case you have to specify the context for that route, like `main_app.edit_user_registration_path`.