# Devise not working after update, Tests via capybara complete without failures

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, capybara, nomethoderror

I'm quite new to RoR and programmed a couple of things before discovering Test-Driven-Development. So I tried to write some tests with guard-rspec and capybara. All was fine, but I got some deprecation warnings for devise (had version 1.1.rc02), so I updated it (now having latest version 1.4.5).

These were the warnings:

Running all specs

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Using form_for(:name, @resource) is deprecated. Please use form_for(@resource, :as => :name) instead. (called from _app_views_devise_sessions_new_html_erb___942904761_2291541620_0 at /Users/xonic/Documents/work/ror.ror.at/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb:3)
FDEPRECATION WARNING: Using form_for(:name, @resource) is deprecated. Please use form_for(@resource, :as => :name) instead. (called from _app_views_devise_sessions_new_html_erb___942904761_2291541620_0 at /Users/xonic/Documents/work/ror.ror.at/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb:3)
.DEPRECATION WARNING: Using form_for(:name, @resource) is deprecated. Please use form_for(@resource, :as => :name) instead. (called from _app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb__1735759005_2291086140_0 at /Users/xonic/Documents/work/ror.ror.at/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:3)
```

So I changed

```
<%= form_for(resource_name, resource, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for(resource, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

and got rid of the warnings. So far so good, I continued with my tests and did not try to open the application in the browser myself.

I'm not sure what happened then but all of a sudden, when trying to open the application in the browser, i get the following error message:

```
NoMethodError in Slides#index

Showing /Users/xonic/Documents/work/ror.ror.at/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #27 raised:

private method `split' called for #<Class:0x10c023278>
Extracted source (around line #27):

24: 
25:                 <div class="gopro">
26: 
27:                     <% if user_signed_in? %>
28:                         Signed in as <%= link_to current_user.username, user_path(current_user) %>. Not you? <%#, user_slides_path(current_user.username) %>
29:                         <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path %>
30:                     <% else %>
```

So obviously, Devise is in trouble... no idea why. Funny thing is, when calling `save_and_open_page` while testing the app, a browser window opens with the application displaying correctly and no errors at all.

```
Guard::RSpec is running, with RSpec 2!
Running all specs
...

Finished in 0.95467 seconds
3 examples, 0 failures
```

**UPDATE:**
I've seen this very similar question [Devise: NoMethod Error & user_signed_in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116484/devise-nomethod-error-user-signed-in) and have correctly set up the user model, so that's not the problem.

This is quite confusing to me, hopefully someone out there understands what's happening *crossingFingers*

Thanks,
xon1c

**UPDATE**
I fixed it, but stackoverflow won't let me answer my own question in the next 6hrs because of lack of reputation *sigh*. Will post the solution later.

Comment: If you run the server in test mode (`rails server -e testing`) then does the page open in the browser correctly?

Comment: My bad, you need `rails server -e test` instead. apologies

Comment: Got the server running with the test database and when opening the page i get the following error: Internal Server Error

private method `split' called for #<Class:0x10cafad40>
WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.8.7/2010-01-10) at localhost:3000

Comment: yeah, well I should've looked at the command before executing it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it (close to perfect). Here's what i did:

I reverted git to a working status and began from scratch. This time I did not use the line

```
gem 'devise', :git => 'git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git'
```

in my Gemfile, instead I only put

```
gem 'devise'
```

and then installed the latest devise gem through

```
gem install devise
rails generate devise:install
```

The command installed version 1.4.5, not 1.4.7 as I previously had. Then I installed all the other gems, namely capybara, guard-rspec, factory_girl_rails and launchy. Everything works fine now except these two warnings I'm left with:

```
Running: spec/requests/sign_ups_spec.rb
DEPRECATION WARNING: :name_prefix was deprecated in the new router syntax. Use :as instead. (called from /Users/xonic/Documents/work/ror.ror.at/config/routes.rb:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: :name_prefix was deprecated in the new router syntax. Use :as instead. (called from /Users/xonic/Documents/work/ror.ror.at/config/routes.rb:7)
.

Finished in 0.16255 seconds
1 example, 0 failures
```

Well, as long as everything works, I'm ok with the warnings but if anybody knows how to get rid of them, please let me know.

Thanks.