# undefined method `user_signed_in?' for #<ProjectsController:0x007faead1853e0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

I'll want to make a authentication with Ruby on Rails, that every user have their own account.  But now i gett this error:

```
undefined method user_signed_in? for #<ProjectsController:0x007faead1853e0>
```

Could somebody help me?

Here is the code:

**Full trace:**

```
app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:69:in `require_login'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__2505248868868045404__process_action__114470166732456289__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:205:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:467:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__4031929640367205598__call__2058268190974805736__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/Users/sinaoberle/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/sinaoberle/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/sinaoberle/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

**projects_controller.rb**

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_login
  # GET /projects
  # GET /projects.json
  def index
    @projects = current_user.projects

  end

  # GET /projects/1
  # GET /projects/1.json
  def show
    @projects = current_user.projects.find(params[:id])

  end

  # GET /projects/new
  # GET /projects/new.json
  def new
    @projects = current_user.projects.build

  end

  # GET /projects/1/edit
   def show
    @projects = current_user.projects.find(params[:id])

  end

  # POST /projects
  # POST /projects.json
  def create
    @projects = current_user.projects.build(params[:mytime])
      if @projects.save
         redirect_to projects_path,
            notice: 'Created successfully!'
      else
        render 'new'
      end
     end 

  # PUT /projects/1
  # PUT /projects/1.json
  def update
    @projects = current_user.projects.find(params[:id])
      if @projects.update_attributes(params[:mytime])
        redirect_to projects_path,
            notice: 'Changed successfully!'
      else
        render 'edit'

   end
 end

  # DELETE /projects/1
  # DELETE /projects/1.json
  def destroy
    @projects = current_user.projects.find(params[:id])
    @projects.destroy
    redirect_to projects_url,
        notice: 'Deleted successfully!'

  end
end 

private

def require_login
  unless user_signed_in?
    redirect_to login_path,
    alert: "Please, Sign In first!"
end 
end
```

**application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">

    <div id="content">
        <% if flash[:notice] %>
        <p id="notice">
            <%= flash[:notice] %>
        </p>
        <% end %>

        <% if flash[:alert] %>
        <p id= "alert">
            <%= flash[:alert] %> 
        </p>
        <% end %>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    <%= link_to "Sign In", new_user_path %> |
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <%= link_to "Logout", logout_path, method: :delete %> |
        <%= link_to "Test", projects_path %>
        <% else %>
        <%= link_to "Login", login_path %>
        <% end %> 
        <%= yield %>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**routes.rb**

Projects::Application.routes.draw do

```
  get "pages/home"

  resources :projects
  resources :users, :only => [:new, :create]
  resources :sessions, :only => [:create]

  get "login" => "sessions#new", as: "login"
  post "sessions" => "sessions#create", as: "sessions"
  delete "logout" => "sessions#destroy", as: "logout"

  root to: 'pages#home'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you using devise for authentication? i haven't used it myself but by looking at the [devise code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L18) and [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) it looks like you should do `before_filter :authenticate_user!` in the controller (or some parent controller class) where you want to use helpers like `user_signed_in?`.

Note that since Rails 5.1 you have to use `before_action` instead.

Comment: @UserS so this was the actual problem?

Comment: please update this answer because `before_filter` is deprecated in Rails 5.0 and has been removed in Rails 5.1. The new syntax for `before_filter` is `before_action`.

Answer (score 1):

## **How did you generate your devise model?**

In my case, I generated it in a different manner. If you generated it like this:

```
rails g devise User/Person
```

Then you should be able to use this in your controller to make sure user is signed_in before viewing the page:

Notice I am using **person** instead of **user**

```
before_action :authenticate_person!
```

To check if they are signed in, do like so:

```
    <% if person_signed_in? %>
        <p>You are signed in</p>
    <% else %>
        <p>Aww you are not signed in!</p>
    <% end %>
```

The trick is to understand that those helper are auto generated based on how you generated your Devise model initially.

It is documented on Devise's github:

> Notice that if your Devise model is called Member instead of User, for
>   example, then the helpers available are:
>
> ```
> before_action :authenticate_member!
>
> member_signed_in?
>
> current_member
>
> member_session
> ```

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

## NOTE:

`:authenticate_user_person` like the one I generated does not work, I do not know as to why it picked the last part only. If you are not sure, usually the error page will show you:

"Did you mean #your_devise_model_name_here#?"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you install authentication gem devise. Method 'user_signed_in?
' isn't built-in in rails3.

See [Devise: NoMethod Error & user_signed_in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116484/devise-nomethod-error-user-signed-in)

Comment: which command should i use? I put this in my gem file : gem 'devise', '2.1.0.rc2'

Comment: If your using bundle you should probably run `bundle install` to make sure all gems are installed.

Comment: Now i get the same error but linked to the application.html.erb ( footer) .

Comment: You need to be more specific what you have changed and include stack trace logs etc if people should be able to help.