# Rails 3.2: No Method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Im trying to display the  current users name in a button in my nav if they are signed in.. I dont use the Home controller for anything, why is it asking for name to be defined in there? Any page involving a different controller give an error when trying to render user.name in the nav..

```
NoMethodError in Home#index

Showing /Users/nelsonkeating/Desktop/ReminDeal/app/views/layouts/_navigation.html.erb where line #10 raised:

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #10):

7: <% if user_signed_in? %>
8:  <div class="logout1">
9:      <div class="btn-group">
10:             <button class="btn"><Action> <%= @user.name %> </button>
11:             <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
12:                 <span class="caret"></span>
13:             </button> 
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method=>'delete' %></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'My Account', edit_user_path(current_user.id)  %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you declared the @user in the controller?
Try changing the line 10 to:

```
  <button class="btn"><Action> <%= current_user.name %> </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this other thread in stackoverflow and it seems the same issue:

[Devise: NoMethod Error & user_signed_in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116484/devise-nomethod-error-user-signed-in)

You seem to be missing the call to devise :database_authenticatable in your User model.